# Unable to set skin manually provided by smartadmin

Tags: angular, smartadmin

I am using angular version of smartadmin in which by default 5 skins comes with it. Dark Elegance, Ultra White, Google Pixel etc. I want to set the skin manually from the code because I don't need that settings button on the right of my web application. When I looked at the documentation, they mentioned that we need to hardcode the skin name as a class in body tag.

```
<body class="smart-style-2">
    ...
</body>
```

I tried the same but it's not working for me. I want to set the skin programatically, not from any side settings.

Comment: AngularJS or Angular 5?

Comment: @YashJain angular 5th version

Answer (score 0):

You can set the skin from smartadmin config file present inside shared folder.

There's a property in this named as `smartSkin`. By default its set to `smart-style-0`.

You can hardcode your skin style for your application here.

**smartadmin.config.ts**

```
export const config: any = {

  defaultLocale: "us",

  API_URL: "assets/api",

  menu_speed: 200,

  smartSkin: "smart-style-0", // Here you set skin for application 

  ...

}
```

For the complete list of skins , refer this.

[Smartadmin Skins](http://192.241.236.31/smartadmin/BUGTRACK/track_/documentation/index.html#!/smartadmin_skins)

Comment: Thank you :) . It was not working when I set the class property of body to the skin name which I want but this is working for me.